# How can i align my text at center with the SVG element?

Tags: html, css

I want to center my text that is below my SVG element, i have attached an image with this post hence you will be able to understand wh. I am new to Bootstrap, CSS and HTML hence this is what i have tried so far:

```
<div class="div1">
<div>
            <h3>
  Manager Success Center
  </h3>
   </div>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row div2">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                    &emsp;<a><svg width="3.5em" height="3.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-file-earmark-ruled" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5 10H3V9h10v1H6v2h7v1H6v2H5v-2H3v-1h2v-2z"/>
                <path d="M4 0h5.5v1H4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.5h1V14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z"/>
                <path d="M9.5 3V0L14 4.5h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9.5 3z"/>
              </svg>
          <br>
              <h4>Hiring for Quality</h4>
              <p>Resources for Hiring</p></a>
              
      </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                        &emsp;&emsp;<a><svg width="3.5em" height="3.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-building" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.763.075A.5.5 0 0 1 15 .5v15a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V14h-1v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V10a.5.5 0 0 1 .342-.474L6 7.64V4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .276-.447l8-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .487.022zM6 8.694L1 10.36V15h5V8.694zM7 15h2v-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V15h2V1.309l-7 3.5V15z"/>
  <path d="M2 11h1v1H2v-1zm2 0h1v1H4v-1zm-2 2h1v1H2v-1zm2 0h1v1H4v-1zm4-4h1v1H8V9zm2 0h1v1h-1V9zm-2 2h1v1H8v-1zm2 0h1v1h-1v-1zm2-2h1v1h-1V9zm0 2h1v1h-1v-1zM8 7h1v1H8V7zm2 0h1v1h-1V7zm2 0h1v1h-1V7zM8 5h1v1H8V5zm2 0h1v1h-1V5zm2 0h1v1h-1V5zm0-2h1v1h-1V3z"/>
</svg>          
      
      <br>
              <h4>Onboarding &amp; Ramp-Up</h4>
              <p>Getting Ready for Day 1 &amp; Beyond</p></a>
      
      </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                        &emsp;<a><svg width="3.5em" height="3.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-cpu" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V2A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 14 4.5h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-2.5 2.5v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V14h-1v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V14h-1v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V14h-1v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V14A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2 11.5H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H2v-1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H2v-1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H2v-1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H2A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 4.5 2V.5A.5.5 0 0 1 5 0zm-.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3 4.5v7A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 4.5 13h7a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-7A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11.5 3h-7zM5 6.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 5h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11 6.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9.5 11h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5 9.5v-3zM6.5 6a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3z"/>
</svg>
              <br>
              <h4>Manage Team &amp; Work</h4>
              <p>Performance &amp; HR Resources</p></a>
      </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                        &emsp;<a><svg width="3.5em" height="3.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-person-badge-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm4.5 0a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-3zM8 11a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm5 2.755C12.146 12.825 10.623 12 8 12s-4.146.826-5 1.755V14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-.245z"/>
</svg>          
      <br>
              <h4>Grow Team &amp; self</h4>
              <p>Career Development</p></a>
      </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[This is how the text is showing up:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxZJa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct HTML tool for this is the `figure` element - has has a display element (usually an image - but it can be anything including an svg) and a `figcaption` that is usually the first or last child of hte figure element. The figutre is used to collated visual elements with descriptions or related text and all the parts can be styled. In this case - its as simple as applying a text-align: center to the figutre element to get the stylnig you are after.

Note that I am following your code structure of having the a element wrap all other content - but I would probably not do it that way if I was doing it. At one time you could not really wrp the a around other elements like this, but HTML 5 allows inline level elements wrapping around block level elements - so that is fine - but you would probably need to style the content to remove the underlines of hover etc.

Also - the h4 and p elements will have styling on them - margins / paddings that you may want to address and customise - but this shows the effect you are after.

Also - note that in the small snippet window - the icons are arranged in towo rows of two - this is due to the boodtstrap xs-6 classes you have - if you want to see them in one row - use the "view in full screen button in the snippet window.

```css
figure {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="div1">
  <h3> Manager Success Center</h3>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row div2">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <a>
        <figure>
             <svg width="3.5em" height="3.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-file-earmark-ruled" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5 10H3V9h10v1H6v2h7v1H6v2H5v-2H3v-1h2v-2z"/>
            <path d="M4 0h5.5v1H4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v12a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.5h1V14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z"/>
            <path d="M9.5 3V0L14 4.5h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9.5 3z"/>
          </svg>
          <figcaption>
           <h4>Hiring for Quality</h4>
            <p>Resources for Hiring</p>
          </figcaption>
         </figure>
       </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <a>
          <figure>
            <svg width="3.5em" height="3.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-building" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.763.075A.5.5 0 0 1 15 .5v15a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V14h-1v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V10a.5.5 0 0 1 .342-.474L6 7.64V4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .276-.447l8-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .487.022zM6 8.694L1 10.36V15h5V8.694zM7 15h2v-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V15h2V1.309l-7 3.5V15z"/>
            <path d="M2 11h1v1H2v-1zm2 0h1v1H4v-1zm-2 2h1v1H2v-1zm2 0h1v1H4v-1zm4-4h1v1H8V9zm2 0h1v1h-1V9zm-2 2h1v1H8v-1zm2 0h1v1h-1v-1zm2-2h1v1h-1V9zm0 2h1v1h-1v-1zM8 7h1v1H8V7zm2 0h1v1h-1V7zm2 0h1v1h-1V7zM8 5h1v1H8V5zm2 0h1v1h-1V5zm2 0h1v1h-1V5zm0-2h1v1h-1V3z"/>
          </svg>          
            <figcaption>
              <h4>Onboarding &amp; Ramp-Up</h4>
              <p>Getting Ready for Day 1 &amp; Beyond</p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <a>
          <figure>
            <svg width="3.5em" height="3.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-cpu" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V2A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 14 4.5h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-2.5 2.5v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V14h-1v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V14h-1v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V14h-1v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V14A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2 11.5H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H2v-1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H2v-1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H2v-1H.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H2A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 4.5 2V.5A.5.5 0 0 1 5 0zm-.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3 4.5v7A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 4.5 13h7a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-7A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11.5 3h-7zM5 6.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 5h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11 6.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9.5 11h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5 9.5v-3zM6.5 6a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3z"/>
            </svg>
            </figcaption>
              <h4>Manage Team &amp; Work</h4>
              <p>Performance &amp; HR Resources</p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <a>
          <figure>
            <svg width="3.5em" height="3.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-person-badge-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2zm4.5 0a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-3zM8 11a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm5 2.755C12.146 12.825 10.623 12 8 12s-4.146.826-5 1.755V14a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h8a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-.245z"/>
            </svg>          
          <figcaption>
            <h4>Grow Team &amp; self</h4>
            <p>Career Development</p>
          </figcaption>
         </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```